# How do I join two tables together if and only if an id is linked to multiple rows in the second table in SQL Server CE?

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I don't know if my title correctly conveys the query I'm trying to achieve, so please edit or suggest a better one that is more correct. I'm trying to join these two tables together:

Table 1: **people**

```
id |field1|field2|
------------------
1  
2
3
4
.
.
. (etc)
```

Table 2: **foods**

```
person.id | name
1         | chicken
1         | pork
1         | beef
2         | pork
2         | chicken
3         | chicken
4         | beef
.
. (etc)
```

I need to join these tables based on a search for any people whose ID is matched with *both* pork or chicken. For example, if I search for `pork`, 1 and 2 should be returned, and if I search for `pork` and `chicken`, 1 and 2 should still be returned, but 3 will not be because it doesn't match `chicken` as well as `pork`. If I search for `pork`, `chicken`, and `beef`, only 1 should be returned.

I've been looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10012695/sql-statement-using-where-clause-with-multiple-values), but I don't know how many items I'll be searching for (I could be searching for `pork` and `chicken` one time, and `pork`, `chicken`, or `beef` another time).

I started out trying the basic `WHERE` clause, which I was fairly certain was faulty (I confirmed this because the query didn't work):

```
SELECT p.id 
FROM people p, foods f 
WHERE p.id = f.person_id AND (f.name = 'pork' AND f.name = 'chicken')
```

but this returns no results. I seem to remember from an SQL tutorial several years ago that I should be using the [`EXISTS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174632) keyword along with a subquery, but I'm not sure how to shape my query/queries based on that.

EDIT: SQL Server CE doesn't support the `INTERSECT` keyword, so unfortunately that option isn't available to me.

Comment: Try this question: [How to filter SQL results in a has-many-through relation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation) Queries 1, 2, 7, 8, 10 and 11 can use a variable-size filter list.

Comment: And how are you getting the values that you need to look up?, why don't you know how many you are looking for?

Comment: @Lamak The values come from user input, so I could calculate the number of items. That's probably the only way to do this query, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can costruct your list `('chicken', 'pork', 'beef')` and count the items in your application:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM   people AS p
  JOIN (
   SELECT person_id
   FROM   foods
   WHERE  name IN ('chicken', 'pork', 'beef')   --- list
   GROUP  BY person_id
   HAVING COUNT(*) = 3                          --- list size
   ) AS pf ON pf.person_id = p.id ;
```

Comment: Since this returns a list of person id's, I should be able to use this entire query as a subquery in a larger query, correct? I think eventually this query will be paired with another similar query, intersected (the SQLCE equivalent, that is) and used as the target of an `IN` keyword. I'll let you know tomorrow if this query is successful.

Comment: Also thanks for posting that link in your previous comment; that's quite helpful and has a lot of good queries to study.

Comment: @pythonscript Note this is essentially the same query you rejected in the referenced answer in your question because, "I don't know how many items I'll be searching for".

Comment: @RedFilter You're right. I seemed to remember hearing of a better way to perform this query, without knowing the number of items, but I believe I was mistaken. I'm just waiting until I can check this query against the database to make absolutely sure.

Comment: That worked perfectly, ypercute. Exactly what I was looking for, and it worked when I fit this query in as a tidbit of my larger overall query. Thank you!

Comment: @pythonscript: note that this is actually Lindoff's first query (which I didn't notice when I posted).

Comment: And as in my linked question, having multiple Joins or Exists (as many as the number of your items) is **faster**.

Answer (score 2):

Use a group by instead:

```
select id
from foods
where name in (<list of foods>)
group by id
having count(*) = <size of list>
```

You can -- horror of horrors -- actually store the list in a string and get the right result.  Say you have:

```
declare @foodlist varchar(8000) = 'pork,chicken'
```

Then the following query works:

```
select id
from foods
where charindex(','+name+',', ','+@foodlist+',') > 0
group by id
having count(*) = 1 + len(@foodlist) - len(replace(@foodlist, ',', ''))
```

Comment: Why should one use this (horror as you say)?

Comment: Interesting horror, though I'm guessing the performance would suffer.

Comment: @ypercube . . . He wants to flexibly create a list of foods.  This is one way of doing so without having to modify the query.  Of course, he could put the list in a temporary table.  This is just an alterntive approach.

Comment: Note this could return incorrect results if the same food is listed more than once for a person.

Comment: @RedFilter That isn't a concern in this database, based on the way it's populated, but because I'm using SQL *Compact Edition*, which doesn't support `DECLARE`, these queries aren't an option for me.

Comment: And also if there were spaces after the commas and in other situations.  It is intended as a possible approach for solving the problem for variable numbers of foods without resorting to temporary tables, cursors, or dynamic SQL.

Comment: @GordonLinoff However, it doesn't apply to SQL Compact Edition, which [doesn't support `DECLARE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173372%28v=SQL.110%29.aspx).

Comment: The first query seems perfectly ok when there is a composite unique key over (person,food) in table foods. Very elegant!

Comment: @pythonscript I was referring to the first query.

Comment: @RedFilter Ah, ok. I'll test that query as well when I have a chance tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.id 
FROM people p INNER JOIN foods f 
ON p.id = f.person_id 
WHERE f.name in (`list of f.name`)
```

> If I search for pork, chicken, and beef, nothing should be returned

According to your table **1** should be returned.

Comment: You're right, I updated the question. I'll try this query out when I have the chance. Doesn't this query return any results that match one food OR the other, though?