# SQL search query with multiple values using in statement

Tags: sql-server, database, sorting, where-in

i am very new to sql databases and i have the following question

I need to search in the component table for all components that have the ID's matching a list of ID's (see example).

**Component table**

```
ID      Name   
1       component 1
...     ...
10      component 10
```

**List of ID's = (1,8,3)**

```
query for this: 
SELECT * FROM Component
WHERE ID IN (1,8,3)
```

This will give me ID 1,3 and 8, that is correct, but in a different order.
Is there a way to keep the order like the order of the list (1,8,3 instead of 1,3,8)?

the link that provided the query: [SQL Statement using Where clause with multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10012695/sql-statement-using-where-clause-with-multiple-values)

Thanks in advance,
Theo

Comment: SQL results have no implicit order. That holds for *all* databases, not just SQL Server. Unless you use an `ORDER BY` clause, the server will return results as they are produced.

Comment: Why do you want to return results in *that* order? Is there some logic behind it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may order using a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT *
FROM Component
WHERE ID IN (1,8,3)
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN ID = 1 THEN 1
         WHEN ID = 8 THEN 2
         ELSE 3 END;
```

But a much better long term solution might be to maintain a separate table of target `ID` values and their ordering:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 1 AS ID, 1 AS position UNION ALL
    SELECT 8, 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 3
)

SELECT c.*
FROM Component c
INNER JOIN cte t
    ON c.ID = t.ID
WHERE c.ID IN (1,8,3)
ORDER BY t.position;
```